# Increase version after commit to master in VSTS

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Our application uses VSTS for our CI flow and we have a requirement that the patch version should increase by one each time code is merged back into master.

We have created a shell script that will bump the version of the application and tag the repo, but now we are looking for the best place in the flow to inject it. We've thought of the following:

1. **Master commit hook build** - The problem with putting this here is that we have protected the master branch with certain policies (must resolve all comments, project must build, etc). Because of this, the build agent runs the script does not have access to push changes.
2. **Pull Request build** - This option would integrate the script into the build job that is used to verify the build. This actually works, but when the updates are pushed to the branch, this triggers an infinite build loop because the PR automatically rebuilds the branch. In general, this option seems more brittle.

I would love to have option 1 work out, but despite all attempts to grant the agent proper roles, it still does not have access to the repo. We're getting the following error:

`TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.`

Is there a standard way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: What't the version do you want to increase, it's a tag version to record the commits on `master` branch or it's a version for a certain file etc? Do you want to add the increment version before CI build or through CI build? And since you set branch policy on `master` branch, you can not push changes directly on `master` branch (need to use pull request).

Comment: @Marina-MSFT - We are wanting to increase our application version number which is stored in a source code file. Upon successful merge into master, we would then tag master with this version so we have a reference point for releases. Ideally, this is all automated through the CI process to take it out of the dev’s hands.

Comment: I added an answer for update the file version and add a tag during the build. But the task status is failed even the changes and tags are pushed correctly. If it's also suitable for your situation, you can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

To update the file version and add tag for the new commit through CI build, you can add a **PowerShell task**. detail steps as below:

1. Set permission and configure in build definition

   First go to Version control Tab, allow below items for Build Service:

   - Branch creation: Allow
   - Contribute: Allow
   - Read: Inherited allow
   - Tag creation: Inherited allow

   Then in your build definition, add the variable `system.prefergit` as `true` in Variable Tab, and enable **Allow script to access OAuth token** in Options Tab.

   More details, you can refer [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/scripts/git-commands).
2. Add powershell script

   ```
   git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%" fetch
   git checkout master
   # Get the line of the file that contain the version
   # split the line, and only get the version number major.minor.patch.
   # check the version numbers (such as if patch less than 9) and increase the version
   #replace the old version with new version in the file
   git add .
   git commit -m 'change the version as $newVersion'
   git tag $newVersion
   git push origin master --tags
   ```

**Note:** Even the new version and tag can push to remote repo successful, the PowerShell task may failed. So you should set the task after PowerShell task with custom option as Even if a previous task has failed.

Comment: I have followed all of these steps exactly (see full shell script here: https://pastebin.com/NqRqjKXi) but I am still getting the same error: "Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch". The article you referenced is over a year old and some of the verbiage and interface is different. Is it possible this details of this technique have been updated?

Comment: Marina Liu - Any thoughts?

Comment: @TylerMurry I had the same problem. In order to make this solution work, I had to include the token in the `push` command itself, i.e. `git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%" push origin master --tags`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update your branch policy per documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops#git-repository-object-level

Try updating your branch policy with to "Allow" "Bypass policies when pushing"